# move Images in Document Directory

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

Please, I need to move the images from folder to another  folder  in document directory please how can i move these images .

The following my code:

```
 let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    do {
        let document = try fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
        let getFolders = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(document, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

        for folder in getFolders {
            if folder.lastPathComponent! == cell.folderNameLabel.text!   {

                for url in imageUrls {
                    // ImageUrls is the array of all url which i want to move it to another folder 
              try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(NSURL(string: url)!, toURL: folder)           
                }                   
            }
        }
    }catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

I have receive this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   lldb

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line you getting this error

Comment: in this line    try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(NSURL(string: url)!, toURL: folder)

Comment: for accessing local files with NSURL you should try  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: <#T##String#>)

Comment: i do it like you say to me i have receive this error   NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AEA8FFD9-9EDD-4EDF-8F5E-8E0B09C247FF/data/Containers/Data/Application/793F06DC-ED77-4309-98FD-4433817C700D/Documents/Mustafa, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b778f80 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}